# # tag Not rewrite in htaccess file

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i am facing problem with # tag in .htaccess file.. 
problem is

```
       http://localhost/query/index.php?string=abc%23123
```

here we encode query string by `urlencode()` method.

actual value is

> abc#123

but its creating a problem on `$_REQUEST[]` method..

so some one suggest me to use `urlencode()`.

I used it by accepted the suggestion. But now it creating problem in
url rewriting.

.htaccess code is

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+).html?$ index.php?string=$1 [NC,L]
```

now when I click query string page

it show `404` not found 
           http://localhost/query/abc%23123.html

so please help me that the page is shown on browser like

> http://localhost/query/abc#123.html

so please suggest me what i will change in my .htaccess file by which the following url will work for me

Comment: Use a NE flag .... [NC,NE,L]

Comment: Starkeen can you suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule with `B` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html?$ index.php?string=$1 [NC,L,QSA,B]
```

This will pass `http://localhost/query/abc%23123.html` unencoded to `index.php`. Inside `index.php` when you use `$_GET['string']` it will print:

```
query/abc#123
```

Comment: thanks now 404 problem solved but the url is save as previous http://localhost/query/abc%23123.html i want it to be http://localhost/query/abc#123.html

Comment: No that cannot be done. If URL is entered like this `localhost/query/abc#123.html` then web server will only see it as `localhost/query/abc`. Browser leaves part after `#` before sending it to server.